# TSQL - Retrieve the row where the date is the nearest of my value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm currently writing a TSQL stored proc who need to retrieve a row who is the nearest of my datetime passed as parameter.

Here is the current code :

```
DECLARE @IdChannel Int
DECLARE @ExactTime Datetime

SET @IdChannel = 1
SET @ExactTime = '2016-01-01 13:31:49.147'

SELECT TOP 1    
    DER.[DER_DTMODIF]
FROM        
    [SGPI]..[DER_DECRO_REGIE] DER
INNER JOIN  
    SGPI..MAI_MACHINE_INPUT MAI ON MAI.MAI_ACTIVE_INPUT = DER.DER_INPUT 
                                AND MAI.MAI_MACHINE_ID = DER.DER_MACHINE_ID
WHERE       
    (@IdChannel IS NULL OR MAI.MAI_RELATIVE_CHA_ID = @IdChannel)
    AND [DER_DTMODIF] /*is the nearest of @ExactTime*/
```

Here is a snapshot of my data. The request must return  2016/01/01 14:00:17.733 :

[image]

Comment: I haven't find this post. Do you want me to close this one ?

Answer (score 1):

You have top 1 in your query but you have no order by. Without an order by you have no way to determine which row will be returned.

How about top 1 and something along these lines.

```
order by ABS(DATEDIFF(second, @ExactTime, DER_DTMODIF))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `ORDER BY` and `TOP`:

```
SELECT TOP 1 DER.[DER_DTMODIF]
FROM SGPI..[DER_DECRO_REGIE] DER INNER JOIN
     SGPI..MAI_MACHINE_INPUT MAI
     ON MAI.MAI_ACTIVE_INPUT = DER.DER_INPUT AND
        MAI.MAI_MACHINE_ID = DER.DER_MACHINE_ID
WHERE (@IdChannel IS NULL OR MAI.MAI_RELATIVE_CHA_ID = @IdChannel)
ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF(ms, DER_DTMODIF, @ExactTime));
```

Note:  If you have a lot of records that match the `WHERE` clause, then this could be inefficient.  If you know that you'll have matching times every day, you might want to change the `WHERE` to something like:

```
WHERE (@IdChannel IS NULL OR MAI.MAI_RELATIVE_CHA_ID = @IdChannel) AND
      ABS(DATEDIFF(ms, DER_DTMODIF, @ExactTime)) < 24*60*60*1000
```

(This is just an example for one day.)

This would reduce the volume of data used for the `ORDER BY`, which can increase performance.